# ListView's recycling mechanism and ViewHolder conflict

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a ListView with 5+ types of views in rows, the problem is:
I have 18 rows 10 is visible on screen, when i scroll down it's load:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,**1**,**2**,**3**,11,**4**,**5**,**6**,**7**
If I do it without ViewHolder everything works fine but all my EditText's is gone because it's creating new view every time and I need to create this view with 40 rows in future.
The code:

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Row row = arrayRows.get(position);

    if (convertView==null) {
        Log.i("LOG", "convertView == null");
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //setting view holder
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        //build rows
        if (row.getClass() == RowTextViewEditText.class) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_textview_edittext, null);
            viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRowTextViewEditText);
            viewHolder.editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editTextRowTextViewEditText);

            RowTextViewEditText rowTextViewEditText = (RowTextViewEditText) row;
            viewHolder.textView.setText(rowTextViewEditText.textViewText);
            viewHolder.editText.setHint(rowTextViewEditText.hint);
            viewHolder.editText.setText(rowTextViewEditText.editTextText);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        if (row.getClass() == RowTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText.class) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_textview_edittext_textview_edittext, null);
            viewHolder.editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editTextRowTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText);
            viewHolder.editText2 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText2RowTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText);
            viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRowTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText);
            viewHolder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2RowTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText);

            RowTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText rowEditTextEditText = (RowTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText) row;
            viewHolder.textView.setText(rowEditTextEditText.textViewText);
            viewHolder.textView2.setText(rowEditTextEditText.textViewText2);
            viewHolder.editText.setText(rowEditTextEditText.editTextText);
            viewHolder.editText2.setText(rowEditTextEditText.editTextText2);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
    }
    //I have at least 5 types of rows
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        Log.i("LOG", "convertView=" + convertView.getTag());
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

This is Logcat:

```
    convertView == null
    convertView == null
    convertView == null
    convertView == null
    convertView == null
    convertView == null
    convertView == null
    convertView == null
    convertView == null
    convertView == null
    convertView == null
    convertView == null
    convertView=com.adamofsky.survey.OrderAdapter$ViewHolder@413b1a30
    convertView=com.adamofsky.survey.OrderAdapter$ViewHolder@413ada10
    convertView=com.adamofsky.survey.OrderAdapter$ViewHolder@4147edf0
    convertView=com.adamofsky.survey.OrderAdapter$ViewHolder@41415f80
    convertView=com.adamofsky.survey.OrderAdapter$ViewHolder@415ad6d0
    convertView=com.adamofsky.survey.OrderAdapter$ViewHolder@41441e18
    convertView=com.adamofsky.survey.OrderAdapter$ViewHolder@4141afb0
```

As I understand from row 10 convertView not null for some reason and it's return me objects of 1,2,3,4.. WHY ?

This is the ViewHolder class:

```
    public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
    TextView textView2;
    EditText editText;
    EditText editText2;
    Spinner spinner;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}
```

I can create an array of views and then by position take'em from there but it's wrong solution and i want to understand why convertView from row invisible row is null
Thanks for advice.

Comment: Before you try to learn the list view and view holder.  I would recommend the [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html). It takes care of all the recycling for you and is the recommended way.

Comment: And please do not use class matching use enum or constants

Comment: drulabs I use class for transfer data from array to row not for enum arrayRows.add(new RowTextViewEditTextSpinner(new String[]{"company"},this.getString(R.string.company_name),this.getString(R.string.or_type_company_name_here),arrayCompanies,"",arrayCompanies.get(0),0));

Answer (score 1):

**First:**

`ListView` (as well as all other `AdapterView`s) has a notion of "view types", which are better thought of as "row types". You should be using `getItemViewType()` and `getViewTypeCount()` to differentiate rows. This allows `ListView` to recycle the proper row layouts when it calls `getView()`.

It's common practice to use `getItemViewType()` inside of `getView()` to determine which row type you are inflating (or recycling), not this weird business you have with checking class types. You shouldn't even need to create those classes at all if you use view types correctly.

Typically each view type has its own ViewHolder. Using the same ViewHolder class for a variety of different view types is confusing.

**Second:**

Never make assumptions about the order of `getView()` calls. `ListView` can call this method at various times for various reasons; it may call it with positions in increasing or decreasing order; it may not even be planning to display the view, only using it for measurement.

**Third:**

As another person has suggested, you should consider using `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`. It also supports different view types and the ViewHolder pattern is enforced by design.

---

For better understanding of ListView, I would refer you to a video called [The World of ListView](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi7z4ef4KrMAhULxmMKHQBWB5oQtwIIJTAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DwDBM6wVEO70&usg=AFQjCNF5_lMTBUGWJz4gD4HgimG5qv4KBQ&sig2=_mFpLR4p2RbPfRQB02LZjQ). Even if you intend to use RecyclerView, the principles in this video are still applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like many people not understand part of logic in my code so i will explain it and than answer my own question.
Using classes is not for enum or detect row types it is for transfer and getting data of my rows in adapter. Every row has different variables and i have to set them in the row and than get them from row for example:

```
class RowTextViewEditTextCheckBox extends Row{
String textViewText; //for set text:name
String hint; //for set text: please type name here
String checkBoxTitle; //for set checkBoxTitle
String editTextText; // for get text after user will fill the field
boolean checkBoxChecked; //for get result of checkbox when user will check it}
```

so I send this object in array

```
arrayRows.add(new RowTextViewEditTextCheckBox(new String[]{"amounts"},this.getString(R.string.burglary),this.getString(R.string.content),this.getString(R.string.amount),"",false));
```

Now back to the question:
This [link](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) helps me to understand my mistakes
Thanks to [Karakuri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1207921/karakuri) for point me to "view types" in ListView

Why all not seen contentViews taken from ViewHolder in wrong type instead creating new contentView of needed type?

Because ListView detecting type of row and if this type already created before and he is in the recycler, his not creating new contentView his returns contentView from recycler with the same type.

So why he is return the wrong type?

Because his don't know how many types of rows you have so by default it's 1 type. in `getViewTypeCount()` you must to set view types count.

If I understand something or everything wrong please let me know.
This is new code that works like a charm:

```
    @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Row row = arrayRows.get(position);
    if (row.getClass()==RowTextViewEditTextSpinner.class){
        return 0;
    }
    if (row.getClass()==RowTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText.class){
        return 1;
    }
    if (row.getClass()==RowTextViewEditTextCheckBox.class){
        return 2;
    }
    if (row.getClass()==RowTextViewEditText.class){
        return 3;
    }
    if (row.getClass()==RowEditText.class){
        return 4;
    }
    if (row.getClass()==RowTextView.class){
        return 5;
    }
    else {
        return 5;
    }
}
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 6;//if types creates by code may be here some logic of counting
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Row row = arrayRows.get(position);
    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    //setting view holders
    ViewHolderTextViewEditTextSpinner viewHolderTextViewEditTextSpinner;
    ViewHolderTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText viewHolderTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText;

    //build rows
    switch (type){
        case TEXTVIEW_EDITTEXT_SPINNER:
            if (convertView==null){
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_textview_edittext_spinner, parent, false);
                viewHolderTextViewEditTextSpinner = new ViewHolderTextViewEditTextSpinner();
                viewHolderTextViewEditTextSpinner.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRowTextViewEditTextSpinner);
                viewHolderTextViewEditTextSpinner.editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editTextRowTextViewEditTextSpinner);
                viewHolderTextViewEditTextSpinner.spinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerRowTextViewEditTextSpinner);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolderTextViewEditTextSpinner);
            }
            else {
                viewHolderTextViewEditTextSpinner = (ViewHolderTextViewEditTextSpinner)convertView.getTag();
            }
            final RowTextViewEditTextSpinner rowEditTextSpinner = (RowTextViewEditTextSpinner)row;
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, rowEditTextSpinner.spinnerStrings);
            viewHolderTextViewEditTextSpinner.textView.setText(rowEditTextSpinner.textViewText);
            viewHolderTextViewEditTextSpinner.editText.setHint(rowEditTextSpinner.hint);
            viewHolderTextViewEditTextSpinner.editText.setText(rowEditTextSpinner.editTextText);
            viewHolderTextViewEditTextSpinner.spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            viewHolderTextViewEditTextSpinner.spinner.setSelection(rowEditTextSpinner.spinnerSelectedPosition);
            break;
        case TEXTVIEW_EDITTEXT_TEXTVIEW_EDITTEXT:
            if (convertView==null){
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_textview_edittext_textview_edittext, parent, false);
                viewHolderTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText = new ViewHolderTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText();
                viewHolderTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText.editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editTextRowTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText);
                viewHolderTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText.editText2 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText2RowTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText);
                viewHolderTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRowTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText);
                viewHolderTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2RowTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolderTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText);
            }
            else {
                viewHolderTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText = (ViewHolderTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText)convertView.getTag();
            }
            RowTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText rowEditTextEditText = (RowTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText)row;
            viewHolderTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText.textView.setText(rowEditTextEditText.textViewText);
            viewHolderTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText.textView2.setText(rowEditTextEditText.textViewText2);
            viewHolderTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText.editText.setText(rowEditTextEditText.editTextText);
            viewHolderTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText.editText2.setText(rowEditTextEditText.editTextText2);
            break;

    }
    return convertView;
}

    static public class ViewHolderTextViewEditTextSpinner{
    TextView textView;
    EditText editText;
    Spinner spinner;
}
static public class ViewHolderTextViewEditTextTextViewEditText{
    TextView textView;
    TextView textView2;
    EditText editText;
    EditText editText2;
}
static public class ViewHolderTextViewEditTextCheckBox{
    TextView textView;
    EditText editText;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}
static public class ViewHolderTextViewEditText{
    TextView textView;
    EditText editText;
}
static public class ViewHolderEditText{
    EditText editText;
}
static public class ViewHolderTextView{
    TextView textView;
}
```

Please let me know if may be better solution or if this is wrong solution